# Using R to extract sample name from the file_name

Tags: r

My data contains a File_name column, where the file_name looks like this:

**10300136747-X1-211181-XYZW-214-12D5-1_S81_mutect2_variants_joint.txt**

My objective is to extract the sample name "X1-211181-XYZW" from it. What function in R can I use to obtain the desired result?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing but still what I understand that you want to extract the "sample name" column from file "10300136747-X1-211181-XYZW-214-12D5-1_S81_mutect2_variants_joint.txt".
If so then you can subset the column from your file df1

```
sampleName <- subset(df1, select = c(3, 5, 14))
```

3, 4, 15 is your column number, you can change it to sample name column number

you can also do the

```
SampleName <- df1[,c(1, 3:5)]
```

1, 3, 4, 5 is your column number, you can change it to sample name column number.

you can use the dput function to make it a one-liner name separated by comma or data.frame to revert back to the column.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a regular expression. You can use regular expressions with the R package stringr. Here is an example :

```
library(stringr)
file_Name <- "10300136747-X1-211181-XYZW-214-12D5-1_S81_mutect2_variants_joint.txt"
regex_Patten <- "[:alpha:]\\d-\\d{6}-[:alpha:]{4}"
str_extract(string = file_Name, pattern = regex_Patten)
```